# if $2$ and $3$ does not divide n, then prove $n^2 = 12q + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need a proof for this statement:

if $2$ does not divide $n$ and $3$ does not divide $n$, then $n^2 = 12q + 1$.

What I have so far:

i) if $2$ does not divide $n$, then $n$ is not even.

Comment: In fact $n^2=24q+1$

Comment: hint : Since $2$ and $3$ does not divide $n$, $n$ needs to be of form $6k\pm 1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $n$ is not prime

Comment: @Hamou Are there composite counter-examples to Hagen's assertion?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* You want to schow that $n^2-1=12q$, i.e. that $(n+1)(n-1)$ is divisible by $4$ and by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

The form of $n$ must be $n=6k+1$ or $n=6k+5$

Comment: that is the hint that my professor gave us, but that would mean $n^2 is = 36k^2 + 12k + 1 ?

Comment: @LeahE  Yes. $n^2=12(3k^2+k)+1$, and $q=3k^2+k$ in this case.

Comment: @LeahE In the other case, $n^2=36k^2+60k+25=12(3k^2+5k+2)+1$ and $q=3k^2+5k+2$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2$ does not divide $n$, $n$ is odd.

Since $3$ does not divide $n$, it leaves remainder of $1$ or $2$.

Case 1: $n \equiv 1 \mod 3$.
i.e. $n = 3k+1$. 
But we need $3k+1$ odd. 
i.e. $3k$ is even.
 i.e. $k$ is even.
 i.e. $n = 3(2k')+1$ for some $k'$.

Find $n^2$

Case 2: $n \equiv 2 \mod 3$
 i.e. $n = 3k+2$.
 But we need $3k+2$ odd.
 i.e. $3k$ is odd.
 i.e. $k$ is odd.
 i.e. $n = 3(2k'+1)+2$ for some $k'$.
Find $n^2$.